# When radio button select check

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, radio-button

I am using radio button on UITableView cell. Firstly radio button unchecked. When radio button is check. I m Scrolling UITableView the radio button is unchecked. Using this code is below

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return 100;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier    = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierFirst    = @"CellFirst";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierFirst];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    }

    NSArray *cellSubs = cell.contentView.subviews;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < [cellSubs count] ; i++) {
        [[cellSubs objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIButton *redioBtn1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)]; 
    [redioBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [redioBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    redioBtn1.tag = ++tagCount;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:redioBtn1];

    UIButton *redioBtn2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 20, 20)]; 
    [redioBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [redioBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    redioBtn2.tag = ++tagCount;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:redioBtn2];

    UIButton *redioBtn3 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 20, 20, 20)]; 
    [redioBtn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [redioBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(selectRadioButon:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    redioBtn3.tag = ++tagCount;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:redioBtn3];

    return cell;


}


-(void)selectRadioButon:(id)sender {


    btnTag = [sender tag];  
    NSArray *arr = self.view.subviews; 
    UITableView *tblCell = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *cellAry = tblCell.subviews;

    for (int i = 0; i <[cellAry count]; i++) {
        UITableViewCell *content = [cellAry objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *contentArry = content.contentView.subviews;
        for (int j = 0; j <[contentArry count]; j++) {
            UIButton *button = [contentArry objectAtIndex:j];
            if (btnTag == button.tag) {
                for (int i = 0; i <[contentArry count]; i++) {
                    UIButton *button = [contentArry objectAtIndex:i];
                    if (btnTag == button.tag) {
                        if ([sender currentImage]==[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioselect.png"]) 

                            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        else
                            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else
                        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radiounselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }

                return;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing:** You should not be adding the UIButton's everytime the cell is loading. You should add them inside `if (cell == nil) block`.

**Next thing:** You should keep track of the selected radio button index (an *int* value) in a sepearate array (a *NSMutableArray*), and select the respective UIButton, outside the `if (cell == nil) block`.

I hope **[this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)** will help you.